# What is 'ps' in pyspark? I need help plotting histograms and boxplots

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

In the ApacheSpark website, it says that to plot a boxplot, I need to do

```
df = ps.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Similarly, for histogram, it says I need to do

```
df = ps.from_pandas(df)
df.plot.hist(bins=12, alpha=0.5)
```

But when I type in `ps`, it returns an error. So what is `ps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `ps` is the shortform of you pandas that we have in pyspark it converts the data into pandas dataframe
you can import it like this

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

and here is the use case of that

```
>>> import pyspark.pandas as ps
>>>
>>> psdf = ps.range(10)
>>> pdf = psdf.to_pandas()
>>> pdf.values
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

further you can visit this site for help
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html